# Make display: table-cell elements stack on top of each other?

Tags: css

I'm building a tumblr template. In tumblr, there is a variable called `{content}` and it may contain one or more `<p>`-tags

```
<p>Foo</p>
<p>Bar</p>
```

I'm trying to center the content vertically inside a div, regardless of the size of the text or the number of paragraphs.

I used the display: table-cell techinque described here:
http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

In short, you add

```
  display: table;
```

to the containing object and

```
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
```

to the object that you want to vertically center.

This works great when you have just one p-tag. But with multiple they don't flow vertically, but rather horizontally. Is there anything you can do about this?

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/dBPF2/1/

Comment: Did you try to set the `p` tags' `width` fixed to a certain value?

Comment: Doesn't help: http://jsfiddle.net/dBPF2/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another containing object around the `<p>` tags that you set to display:table-cell, rather than setting display:table-cell to the `<p>` tags themselves.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Foo</p>
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
</div>

.content {display:table;}
.inner {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: The `.content` wrapper is not strictly needed.  Both my answer and this one lead to the same layout.

Comment: true, but given the unknowns of the OP's code, I figured this was a safer starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to do this?

```
<div>
    <p>First paragraph.</p>
    <p>Second paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/dBPF2/

Comment: Why did you change the display types?

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry, I thought you were trying to recreate what I was doing in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your solution works aswell! However, I have read in some tutorials that you should have a dipslay tab on the containing element of a element that has display: table-cell, I'm not sure why, maybe some browsers need it. Just good to know for future visitors.

Comment: If these people are telling you the truth, you have a great future in front of you! All the best!